# Remove all lines from a string if a character is found, python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, pattern-matching

I have a string like:

```
FIRST CONTINUATION PAGE FOR ITEM 29 – Establishment Information

Add Second Continuation Page for #29


<<
  /ASCII85EncodePages false
  /AllowTransparency false
  /AutoPositionEPSFiles true
  /AutoRotatePages /None
  /Binding /Left
  /CalGrayProfile (Dot Gain 20%)
  /CalRGBProfile (sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
```

I want to remove all lines in the file after << character is found. How do I use a regex to do this

Comment: Why do you think you need a regex for this?

Comment: Exactly, seems to me you could just solve this problem with `find` and string slicing.

Comment: incase you did need a regex, use the lookbehind function to keep things before the <<: `.*(?=<<)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the simplest solution :

```
your_string = "whatever.................."
sliced_string = your_string.split("<<")[0]
```

that's it.

Comment: This isn't working. I want to ignore/delete all lines from the string once this << character is found in a newline

Comment: what do you get ?

Comment: Maybe the problem is elsewhere then, can you edit your question and post your code?

Comment: Sorry, it's working fine. I was actually using a re.sub before with that character before. Thanks man. Upvoted